# Manually added location updates stop working in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on a 1.5 Android application.  Developing in Eclipse 3.4.2 on Windows XP.  I have a MapView, have requested updates, etc.

The problem is that after the first manually injected GPS coordinate, the app stops recognizing that a GPS coord has been sent.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
MapController mc = mapView.getController();

TextView locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LocationBar);

LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener(mc, itemizedOverlay, locationText);

lm.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
    0, 
    0, 
    locationListener);
```

Then MyLocationListener simply changes the value in a TextView to match the new GPS coordinate.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc == null) {
            return;
        }
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        double lng = loc.getLongitude();

        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

        mc.animateTo(p);

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(p, "title", "snippet"));

        String location = String.format("%f lat %f long", lat, lng);

        locationText.setText(location);

    }
```

I added some logging in the onLocationChanged method and it only ever sees a Location the *first* time that I attempt to send an update.  All subsequent ones don't fire the onLocationChanged method.

Additional info:

The logcat output is as follows:

```
10-02 17:22:34.423: INFO/gps(6671): Provider gps is has status changed to 1. Extras: Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]
```

First GPS update is faked:

```
10-02 17:22:49.383: INFO/gps(6671): Location provided by location provider: Location[mProvider=gps,mTime=-1000,mLatitude=25.0,mLongitude=23.0,mHasAltitude=true,mAltitude=0.0,mHasSpeed=false,mSpeed=0.0,mHasBearing=false,mBearing=0.0,mHasAccuracy=false,mAccuracy=0.0,mExtras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]]
10-02 17:22:49.444: INFO/gps(6671): Provider gps is has status changed to 2. Extras: Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]
```

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html#AVAILABLE , that 2 maps to "Available".

As soon as that "Available" gets set, no other locations get passed through.  Seems a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: Sending the GPS locations via the geo fix command through telnet manifests the same problem... only the first location update is ever heard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are experiencing a bug in the GPS driver of the emulator.

A workaround for the 1.5 versions of the SDK is from [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36907684) **#39**.

> In the emulator, on the Home Screen, press
>
> Menu ->   Settings ->
> Date & Time -> (Uncheck )Automatic ->  Select Time Zone
>
> and choose the right time zone (ie, yours).

A [fix](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/36907684#comment43) is included in the 1.6    #43 release of the SDK.

Comment: I haven't tested your answer yet but the bug report you gave is an excellent resource.  I'm glad to find I'm not the only one with this problem!

Interestingly enough, my coworker on a Mac does not have this issue.

Comment: Just tested your solution and it works brilliantly.

I never in a million years would have thought of a link between GPS coordinates and automatically managed time zone settings...