# Android GPS just first location change results in onLocationChanged, why?

Tags: android, eclipse, gps

I am still testing the android gps functionality and got my Eclipse now to deliver one location `onCreate()` with `getLastKnownLocation()`and one `onLocationChanged()` event. But when I send further location changes with the telnet-interface's `geo fix`command I get no further event calls. What might be the reason for that?

My output implies that he starts to listen for changes after starting the App (there is a `GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED` event) and then after recieving a location update he stops listening automatically (there is a `GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED` event).

For details ask and have a look at my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager l =(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> li = l.getAllProviders();
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = li.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String string =  iterator.next();
            Log.i(TAG, string);
    }
    if (l.getLastKnownLocation("gps")==null)
        Log.i(TAG, "null"); 
    else{            
        Log.i(TAG, l.getLastKnownLocation("gps").toString());
    }

    l.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

...

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    String txt = "onStatusChanged:"+arg0+":";
    switch(arg1){
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            txt += "first fix";
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            txt += "sat status";
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            txt += "event started";
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            txt += "event stopped";
    }
    Log.i(TAG, txt);
}

...

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged:" +arg0.toString());
}
```

and here the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mypackage.example.gps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".gpsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for the 1.5 versions of the SDK is included in the bug report.

```
In the emulator, on the Home Screen, press "Menu" -> "Settings" -> "Date & Time" -> Uncheck "Automatic" -> "Select Time Zone", and choose the right time zone (ie, yours).
```

further detail please refer this question ["Manually added location updates stop working in Eclipse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509958/manually-added-location-updates-stop-working-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

Put your location update code in onResume method..

like this,

```
@Override
   public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000L,1.0f, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000L, 1.0f, this);
    locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);

}
```

And also gives the perameters like time in milisecond, and distance in float.

Hope this will help you.

If you find this answer is helpful then please vote it for others.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clear up my code a little. It didn't tackle or solve the problem, though. Btw. people will upvote a helpful response no matter if you ask them to do so or not.

Comment: can you tell me what type of permission given in your manifest file for gps access?

Comment: of course, I added the manifest content to the question above.

Comment: A workaround for the 1.5 versions of the SDK is included in the bug report.                                                                            In the emulator, on the Home Screen, press "Menu" -> "Settings" -> "Date & Time" -> Uncheck "Automatic" -> "Select Time Zone", and choose the right time zone (ie, yours).                                       further detail please refer this question "Manually added location updates stop working in Eclipse".

Comment: Thanks man, that was the solution. can u put that as a new answer that I can give u the upvote and accept that as the solution? Then please also add the link to where u found the solution.

Comment: is that gpsStatusListener(this) refer to the Activity class that implementing LocationListener? @user370305,

Comment: @gumuruh - Yes, That's why we have passed `this` as a parameter.

Comment: but when I tried it, error found. can't accept this. @user370305 any ideas?